# PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist while removing entity with composite key

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I have encounter in JPA/Hibernate odd error... I'm getting

```
PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist
```

When trying to remove ServicePoint entity that has composite key consisting of ProviderId and ServicePointNumber. (Provider is another entity and ServicePoint represents weak entity dependent on Provider entity).

Code looks like below:

```
@DELETE
        @Path("/{servicePointNumber : \\d+}")
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
        public Response removeServicePoint( @PathParam("userId") Long userId,
                                            @PathParam("servicePointNumber") Integer servicePointNumber,
                                            @BeanParam GenericBeanParam params) throws ForbiddenException, NotFoundException {

            if(params.getAuthToken() == null) throw new ForbiddenException("Unauthorized access to web service.");
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "removing given Service Point by executing ProviderResource.ServicePointResource.removeServicePoint(userId, servicePointNumber) method of REST API");

            // find ServicePoint entity that should be deleted
            ServicePoint toDeleteServicePoint = servicePointFacade.find( new ServicePointId(userId, servicePointNumber) );
            // throw exception if entity hasn't been found
            if(toDeleteServicePoint == null)
                throw new NotFoundException("Could not find service point to delete for given id: " + userId + ".");

            // remove entity from database
            servicePointFacade.remove(toDeleteServicePoint);

            return Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
        }
```

and implementation of entity facade remove method:

```
public void remove(@NotNull T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }
```

Comment: What are you using for transaction management? Also the complete stack trace and the code for your composite key will be instructive.

Comment: I am using @Stateless session bean Transaction type REQUIRED on remove method. On the other hand removeServicePoint doesn't have any transaction it is method on JAX-RS Resource class. I have tried to use \@Transactional but this didn't help. \@Transactional seems to not work? this resource class is non-static subclass of another resource class. I have made work around using \@NamedQuery: DELETE FROM ServicePoint sp WHERE sp.provider.userId = :userId AND sp.servicePointNumber = :servicePointNumber . It works but it seems odd that I cannot just delete using entity manager .remove() method

Comment: What is the implementation of getEntityManager() method?

Comment: It just return EntityManger object. As this method (remove()) is in AbstractFacade with EntityManager property set on subclass and has abstract method that should be overridden and return this EntityManager suitable to given Entity

Answer (score 0):

in a sometime you are using Evict? or some session.clear?

Comment: No I am not using the problem is with composite primary key and that provider Id is inherited from provider entity... and this provider entity is detached. The same code with single primary key field works correctly.

Comment: I have also tried to use @Transactional annotation on this method and it didn't help